# Check if an array is inside another array - C programming

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

The task is to search if an array can be found in another array. There are four parameters in the function, all of them are pointers.

```
*p1, *p2, *q1, *q2
```

p1 and p2 are pointing to the beginning and behind the end of the first array respectively, the same goes for q1 and q2, they are just for the second array. If the second array is found in the first one, the function has to return the index of the first element in the first array which is also the beginning of the second array. If no such array is found the function has to return back the value -1. For example if we have two arrays

```
Niz1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
Niz2[] = {2, 3, 4};
```

The result will be 2 because that's the index of the first common element for the arrays. I wrote a code that almost completely works, but for example in the arrays

```
niz1[10]={1,1,2,3,5,6,1,2,3,10};
niz2[10]={1,1,2,3,5,6,1,2,3,10};
```

the output is -1 as if the second array is not in the first, when it should actually be 1, so this has been giving be issues.
This is my code:

```
int Podniz (const int *p1, const int *p2, const int *q1, const int *q2)
{

    int i=0;

    while(*p1!=*q1)
    {
        i++;
        p1++;
    }
    int *pomocni=p1;
    while(pomocni<p2 && q1<q2)
    {
            if(*pomocni == *q1)
            {
                pomocni++;
                q1++;
            }
            else if(*pomocni != *q1)
                return -1;
    }
    return i;
}

int main() {
    int niz1[10]={1,1,2,3,5,6,1,2,3,10};
    int niz2[3]={1,2,3};
    int k = Podniz(niz1, niz1+10, niz2, niz2+3);
    printf("%d", k);
    return 0;
}
```

Can you help me solve this, so my code can be 100% correct?
I added the main part of the code that I forgot, where I use the function. These 2 arrays are the example where I get the wrong output.

```
int Podniz (const int *p1, const int *p2, const int *q1, const int *q2)
{


    int i=0;

    while(*p1!=*q1)
    {
        i++;
        p1++;
    }
    const int *pomocni=p1;
    while(p1<p2)
    {
    while(pomocni<p2 && q1<q2)
    {
            if(*pomocni == *q1)
            {
                pomocni++;
                q1++;
            }
            else if(*pomocni != *q1)
                return -1;
    }
    return i;
}
}
```

I have tried to change my function, as it was suggested but still get -1 as output.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm

Comment: How do you call your `int Podniz (const int *p1, const int *p2, const int *q1, const int *q2)` function?  You need to provide all your code.

Comment: `while(*p1!=*q1)
    {
        i++;
        p1++;
    }` is scary code as the loop can go on and on, well past `p2`.

Comment: I have added the main part of the code.

Comment: Normally in C, array indices start at zero, so the 2,3,4 subsequence is at index 1, not 2, in the first array.  You need to think about how your code would find `{ 2, 3, 4 }` in `{ 1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 6, 2, 2, 3, 4, 7 }`.  I don't see enough looping on failure to match before reaching the end of `[p1..p2)`.

Comment: *"The result will be 2 because that's the index of the first common element for the arrays"* - FALSE. The result will be `1` which is the index within `Niz1` where `Niz2` begins. (arrays are *zero indexed* in C)

Answer (score 0):

First, which is the bug you have. The bug comes from the fact that the first array starts with two ones, while the second array only starts with one. What you are doing wrong is when you try to figure out where in p1 you want to start looking. For those cases where this works out your code seems to be fine.

What you would do is to use this section:

```
while(pomocni<p2 && q1<q2)
{
        if(*pomocni == *q1)
        {
            pomocni++;
            q1++;
        }
        else if(*pomocni != *q1)
            return -1;
}
return i;
```

but wrap it inside a loop and try it for ALL elements in first array. Remember to check for boundary conditions so you don't read outside the arrays.

And one small thing. `int *pomocni=p1;` should be `const int *pomocni=p1;` Pay attention to compiler warnings.

Comment: Putting it in a loop will only help if you don't return immediately.

Comment: I have tried this, but still the same output. I have added the function to my initial question.